# Is there a way to store arrays in an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to store a few arrays that contain Strings in an array. When I want to initialize it I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to specified type '[Array]' Insert' as![Array]​'.

array is created like this:

```
    var array: [String] = []
```

I already tried:

```
var bigArray: [Array] = []
bigArray.append(array)
```

or like this:

```
var bigArray: [Array] = [Array]
bigArray.append(array)
```

and this:

```
var bigArray: [Array] = [Array]as!Array
bigArray.append(array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of string arrays then simply do:

```
var bigArray = [[String]]()
bigArray.append(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a second set of brackets. If you want to make an array of arrays of strings it needs to be of type `[[String]]` not `[String]`:

```
let fruits1 = ["Apples", "Oranges"]
let fruits2 = ["Bananas", "Strawberries", "Cherries"]

var fruitbaskets: [[String]] = []

fruitbaskets.append(fruits1)
fruitbaskets.append(fruits2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try

```
var array: [[String]] = []
```

then you can add arrays like

```
let firstArray = ["one", "two"]
array.append(firstArray)
```